# How do I colour a mesh in Kiss3d?

Tags: materials, uv-mapping, rust

This is a question about the sebcrozet/kiss3d graphics engine for the Rust programming language. I have managed to create a mesh using `group.add_mesh()`. Now I want to colour my mesh with a specified colour for each vertex (or face). Does anyone know how I do this?

One possible approach seems to be to define a `RgbImage` with all my different colours somewhere in the image, turn that into a `DynamicImage`, turn that into a `Texture`, somehow associate the texture with the mesh, set up a UV map, and set the UV location for each vertex to map to the relevant colour.

The documentation does not go into enough detail or give a specific example. Does anyone have any example code that works?

Comment: I have created my own answer, but it does not work. I have raised an issue against the crate at https://github.com/sebcrozet/kiss3d/issues/227

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.